# Creating HTML link to a PDF table of contents section

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with PDF files stored in a network folder that is accessed through Chrome. Each PDF has a responsive table of contents with internal links that allow you to click and go to an individual section. For example, the table of contents lists 20 steps and clicking on step 13 takes you directly to the header "Step 13" on whichever page. How can I create an HTML link directly to Step 13?

I have already considered using "#page=5" skipping directly to the page but as the PDFs are updated the page numbers could become out of sync with the steps.

Also, these PDFs are generated by exporting a .docx file with it's table of contents to .pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/jump-link-same-page
Just create each step in the table as an anchor tag.